# Copy a range from a worksheet

Tags: excel

I want to copy a range from a worksheet in one workbook to a worksheet in another workbook.

But my problem is that the copied formulas/references become relative to the old workbook instead absolute in the new workbook

I have a workbook with a sheet "Get Data " , and then I have a lot of sheets which retrieves data from the "Get Data " but my "Get Data " sheet does not work anymore, I have now created a new "Get Data " sheets in a new workbook and will now have all the sheets into the worbook and retrieve data from the new sheet without making any references again .

Comment: Please include your VBA code and highlight the problematic part. Thanks and regards,

Comment: A good trick is to go into formulaes show formula and copy and paste as text or move tab but use copy option.

Answer (score 0):

If your formulas are named formulas, it will. or it references to some sheet it will. Otherwise I don't see any problem in normal copy and paste operation. it works fine.